# How to format xml using linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

Here i am creating a xml using linq and not getting in the required format.Here is my code

```
List<string> listvalue = new List<string>();
listvalue.Add("http://example.com/sample.html");
listvalue.Add("http://example.com/new.html");
foreach (string url in listvalue)
{
    var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
    var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                    .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                    .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));

    List<string> asList = urls.ToList();
    GenerateXml(url, asList);                       

}
```

and

```
protected void GenerateXml(string url, List<string> listitems)  //generateXml
{

    XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    XNamespace nsImage = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1";

    var sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));

    var urlSet = new XElement(nsSitemap + "urlset",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", nsSitemap),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "image", nsImage),
        new XElement(nsSitemap + "url",
        new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", url),
        from urlNode in listitems
        select new XElement(nsImage + "image",
               new XElement(nsImage + "loc", urlNode)
           )));
    sitemap.Add(urlSet);
    sitemap.Save(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Static/sitemaps/Sitemap-image.xml"));
}
```

I need it in the below format

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
<url>
    <loc>http://example.com/new.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/newimage.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/newphoto.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url>
</urlset>
```

But here i am getting a single url tag. How to achieve this? Any suggestion?

Comment: You're calling `GenerateXml` *inside your loop* in your first piece of code - so you'll only end up with XML for the last iteration. I suspect you don't want that...

Comment: @Jon Skeet:Yep i have tried using dictionary and passed the dictionary value in Generate xml outside loop..But i dont know how to get the format in linq

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>(); myDict.Add(url, asList);GenerateXml(myDict);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is really just a case of wanting to fetch *all* the URLs (from all the source documents) before you call `GenerateXml` at all - and remember where each one came from. That's as simple as:

```
var sources = new List<string>
{
    "http://example.com/sample.html",
    "http://example.com/new.html"
};
var imagesBySource = sources
    .ToDictionary(source => source,
                  source => new HtmlWeb().Load(url)
                               .DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                               .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                               .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                               .ToList());
GenerateXml(imagesBySource);
```

You'd then need to change `GenerateXml` to take a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. Something like (untested):

```
protected void GenerateXml(Dictionary<string, List<string>> imagesByUrl)
{    
    XNamespace nsSitemap = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
    XNamespace nsImage = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1";

    var sitemap = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""));

    var urlSet = new XElement(nsSitemap + "urlset",
        new XAttribute("xmlns", nsSitemap),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "image", nsImage),
        imagesByUrl.Select(entry => 
            new XElement(nsSitemap + "url",
                new XElement(nsSitemap + "loc", entry.Key),
                from urlNode in entry.Value
                select new XElement(nsImage + "image",
                    new XElement(nsImage + "loc", urlNode)
                )
        )
    );
    sitemap.Add(urlSet);
    var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Static/sitemaps/Sitemap-image.xml");
    sitemap.Save(path);
}
```

Note that this won't guarantee that the order of the sources is preserved. If you need that, you should probably create a class with `Url` and `Images` properties, and pass a list of those to `GenerateXml` instead.

Comment: source => new HtmlWeb().Load(url) throws the below error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: So i have used foreach and it is working fine  foreach (string url in listvalue)
            {
                var document = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
                var urls = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
                                                .Select(e => e.GetAttributeValue("src", null))
                                                .Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();
                myDict.Add(url, urls);
            }

Comment: @bala3569: It should be fine - it should be using the second argument to `ToDictionary` as the element selector... will have a look

Comment: @bala3569: It compiles for me, with a couple of quick changes to use `XDocument` instead of `HtmlWeb` (which I haven't seen before).